# Installing FFMPEG with AMF Support on Ubuntu 20.04.5

Tags: video, ffmpeg, gpu-driver, amdgpu

I'm on the AWS g4ad server instance that has AMD Radeon Pro V520 GPU. I am trying to get my ffmpeg to use the GPU when doing conversion as such:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -c:v h264_amf output.mp4
```

When I install normall ffmpeg or use the ffmpeg from ppa:savoury1/ffmpeg4, these not have the amf codec enabled (even though 4.3 is suppose to the code enable by default). I will get this error:

```
Unknown encoder 'h264_amf'
```

Also, the different are installed from here:  https://www.amd.com/en/support/linux-drivers

Then I tried to compile ffmpeg from the source with:

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH" PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig" ./configure \
      --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" \
      --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
      --extra-cflags="-I$HOME/ffmpeg_build/include" \
      --extra-ldflags="-L$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib" \
      --extra-libs="-lpthread -lm" \
      --bindir="$HOME/bin" \
      --enable-libfdk-aac \
      --enable-gpl \
      --enable-libass \
      --enable-libfreetype \
      --enable-libmp3lame \
      --enable-libopus \
      --enable-libvorbis \
      --enable-libvpx \
      --enable-libx264 \
      --enable-libx265 \
      --enable-libtheora \
      --enable-openssl \
      --enable-amf \
      --enable-encoder=h264_amf \
      --enable-nonfree
```

But I get the error

```
ERROR: amf requested but not found
```

And the instructions for how to include AMF are vague.

Can anyone provide a way of getting FFMPEG working with ffmpeg?

Comment: More concrete advice here perhaps: https://ffmpeg.org/general.html#AMD-AMF_002fVCE

Answer (score 1):

Must put AMF repo in home folder

```
cd ~/
git clone https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/AMF.git
sudo mkdir /usr/local/include/AMF
cd /usr/local/include/AMF
sudo ln -sf ~/AMF/amf/public/include/core
sudo ln -sf ~/AMF/amf/public/include/components
```

[optional] Then when you want update and rebuild with new versions only need

```
cd ~/AMF
git pull
```

Then try compile the ffmpeg again with --enable-amf

According to:

> FFmpeg can use the AMD Advanced Media Framework library for
> accelerated H.264 and HEVC(only windows) encoding on hardware with
> Video Coding Engine (VCE).
>
> To enable support you must obtain the AMF framework header
> files(version 1.4.9+) from
> https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/AMF.git.
>
> Create an AMF/ directory in the system include path. Copy the contents
> of AMF/amf/public/include/ into that directory. Then configure FFmpeg
> with --enable-amf.
>
> Initialization of amf encoder occurs in this order: 1) trying to
> initialize through dx11(only windows) 2) trying to initialize through
> dx9(only windows) 3) trying to initialize through vulkan
>
> To use h.264(AMD VCE) encoder on linux amdgru-pro version 19.20+ and
> amf-amdgpu-pro package(amdgru-pro contains, but does not install
> automatically) are required.
>
> This driver can be installed using amdgpu-pro-install script in
> official amd driver archive.